# Xamarin MasterPage - show/hide seperator line within menu

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do I show/hide the seperator line within the menu from a MasterPage? At the moment, all the lines seem to be enabled, but I don't know where they are coming from. I want to disable all line except the line between "Slaap" and "Persoonlijke gegevens". In this picture it looks like there are only two lines, but in reality you can see them all clearly.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EIrA.jpg]

**MasterPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeToSport.Views"
         xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:TimeToSport.Views"
         x:Class="TimeToSport.Views.Main.MasterPage"
         Padding="0,0,0,0" Title="Time To Sport">
<StackLayout>
    <Image Source="HeaderBackground.png" Margin="0,0,0,15"/>
    <ListView x:Name="listView" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Home" IconSource="contacts.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ItemsPage}" />
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Sport" IconSource="contacts.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:SportPage}" />
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Voeding" IconSource="reminders.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:VoedingPage}" />
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Slaap" IconSource="todo.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:SlaapPage}" />
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Persoonlijke Gegevens" IconSource="todo.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:GegevensGewichtDoel}"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="17" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your Listview should have the `SeparatorVisibility=None`,

In your `local: MasterPageItem` add a new Property `IsSeparator`, to identify which element will be separator

Then, in your listview

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" SeparatorVisibility="None" x:FieldModifier="public">
        <ListView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type local:MasterPageItem}">
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Home" IconSource="contacts.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:ItemsPage}" />
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Sport" IconSource="contacts.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:SportPage}" />
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Voeding" IconSource="reminders.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:VoedingPage}" />
                <local1:MasterPageItem IsSeparator="true" Title="Slaap" IconSource="todo.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:SlaapPage}" />
                <local1:MasterPageItem Title="Persoonlijke Gegevens" IconSource="todo.png" TargetType="{x:Type local:GegevensGewichtDoel}"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ListView.ItemsSource>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5,10">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height ="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height ="1"/>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions/>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="17" />

                        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HeightRequest="1" Color="Red" IsVisible="{Binding IsSeparator}">
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Should the `IsSeperator` just be a bool? I've done that and I got the following result: https://i.gyazo.com/24137b43d6756cf47fea764e750a8a01.jpg. What's wrong?

Comment: I forgot to add the Row of the BoxView (which is Grid.Row="1"), check my edited answer.

Comment: And yes, the IsSeparator is just a bool in order to bind directly to the IsVisible Property

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn If it works, don't forget to mark as correct and upvote! :)

Comment: Didn't seem to fix it, got the following result: https://i.gyazo.com/24137b43d6756cf47fea764e750a8a01.jpg

Comment: Updated my answer. You also need to add the Grid.RowSpan="2", for the boxview to occupy the full width of the Grid

Comment: @J.K.Harthoorn the link you provided is the same in the initial version of the answer.

Comment: Sorry about the link. I added RowSpan, but the text is not correctly displayed now: https://i.gyazo.com/acbd9a7a10a1a00939545d40c54ff23a.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187195/discussion-between-bruno-caceiro-and-j-k-harthoorn).